# Type error in code, datetime.date, Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found

Tags: python

I have a problem using datetime in my tkinter program.
The problem looks to be in this line:

```
  user = Person('User', datetime.date(int(year_entry.get())), (int(month_entry.get())), (int(day_entry.get())))
```

Full Code:

```
    import datetime 
    import tkinter as tk

    # GUI
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('200x400')
    window.title('Age calculator')

    info_label = tk.Label(text='Calculate your age!')
    info_label.grid(column=1, row=0)


    year_label = tk.Label(text='Year')
    year_label.grid(column=0, row=1)

    month_label = tk.Label(text='Month')
    month_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

    day_label = tk.Label(text='Day')
    day_label.grid(column=0, row=3)

    year_entry = tk.Entry()
    year_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    month_entry = tk.Entry()
    month_entry.grid(column=1, row=2)

    day_entry = tk.Entry()
    day_entry.grid(column=1, row=3)

    def calculate_age():
        print(year_entry.get())
        print(month_entry.get())
        print(day_entry.get())
        user = Person('User', datetime.date(int(year_entry.get())), (int(month_entry.get())), (int(day_entry.get())))

        print(user.age())
        print('klick!')

        text_answer = tk.Text(master=window, height=20, widt=30)
        text_answer.grid(column=1, row=5)
        text_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Banana!')


    calc_button = tk.Button(text='Calculate!', command=calculate_age)
    calc_button.grid(column=1, row=4)


       class Person:

           def __init__(self, name, birthdate):
               self.name = name
               self.birthdate = birthdate

           def age(self):
               today = datetime.date.today()
               age = today.year - self.birthdate.year
               return age

window.mainloop()
```

I just put in 1 2 and 3 in the entry's and pressed "Calculate" in the GUI.

> Error code:
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1699, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "C:\Users\jimmy\Programming\Apps_OOP\calculator_app.py", line 35, in calculate_age
>       user = Person('User', datetime.date(int(year_entry.get())), (int(month_entry.get())), (int(day_entry.get())))
>   TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found

Please help!

Comment: This is a typo: check your brackets.  In your code, the month and day values are passed as arguments to Person(), not into datetime.date().

Comment: Check your parentheses again. You've way too much

Comment: U guys are AWESOME! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line 35 into this:

```
user = Person('User', datetime.date(int(year_entry.get()), int(month_entry.get()), int(day_entry.get())))
```

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in this span of code:

```
datetime.date(int(year_entry.get()))
```

If you count the parenthesis, you'll see that you're closing off the call to `datetime.date`. Hence the error saying you haven't included required arguments.

The bug is difficult to see because you are trying to do too much in one line of code. You should use temporary variables to store the values from the entry widgets, and then use the variables as arguments to `datetime.date`

For example:

```
year = int(year_entry.get())
month = int(month_entry.get())
day = int(month_entry.get())
date = datetime.date(year, month, day)
user = Person('User', date)
```

It's more lines of code, but more importantly it's more lines of *readable* code. Plus, you have the added benefit of more easily printing out the actual values being passed to the functions.